# proof-general no newline after C-c C-n

Tags: proof-general

I am using proof-general mode for editing and executing Coq files in emacs. However, I am highly annoyed by the `C-c C-n` behavior of always going to the next line if the EoF is reached. As I tend to use it interactively, executing the proof as I go along I end up always typing: `C-c C-n + ARROW-UP + END`.

How can I change that behavior of `C-c C-n` to ONLY evaluate to the next dot? Alternative: Is there a command I overlooked that does exactly that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a way around it I'm having extra commands written on the line, so that end-of-line isn't reached after executing `C-c C-n`: `Proof. .`. That extra dot ensures that when `Proof.` is executed the cursor still stays on the same line.